# update (overwrite) an entire record (all columns) in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

When I am copying rows from one table to another, there is a convenient syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE <table 2 rows have some property>
```

But what if I want to overwrite entire existing rows in table1 with entire rows from table2? So I want something like:

```
UPDATE table1 SET * FROM table2 WHERE <table 1 and 2 rows match on some key field>
```

But from what I can tell, the only way to do this is to enumerate the columns being set one by one (`set table1.columnA = table2.columnA, table1.columnB = table2.columnB`, and so on). Is there some way to say "do it for all the columns" when using UPDATE like there is when using INSERT? If not, why not?

(I guess I could delete all rows from table1 with the given property, and then use the `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT *` syntax to bring in the replacement rows from table2. But that seems like it leaves a bunch of unwanted deleted rows in the database needing to be vacuumed at some point, as opposed to a clean UPDATE where there are no deleted records? Or maybe I'm not understanding the efficiency of a bunch of deletes followed by a bunch of inserts?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such syntax for exactly what you have in mind, and I think you will need to `SET` each column separately.  Also, SQLite does not support a direct update join syntax, but we may use correlated subqueries:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.columnA = (SELECT columnA FROM table2 WHERE table1.col = table2.col),
SET table1.columnB = (SELECT columnB FROM table2 WHERE table1.col = table2.col),
SET table1.columnC = (SELECT columnC FROM table2 WHERE table1.col = table2.col);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know *why* there is no such syntax? Is it because a Delete followed by an Insert achieves the same result and my worry about accumulating deleted row space is not a problem?

Comment: Okay, I'm going with the theory that the intended way to do this is the Delete followed by Insert. From https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html: "When you delete information from an SQLite database, the unused disk space is added to an internal 'free-list' and is reused the next time you insert data. The disk space is not lost. But neither is it returned to the operating system."

Comment: @MKatz I answered on the assumption that you only had a doubt regarding which syntax to use.

Comment: Right, the main question was *why* there didn't appear to be a way to replace records without naming the fields. I knew you could do it by naming the fields. But I have marked your answer as correct. Thanks.